# How to get avg from date range?

Tags: mdx, olap, mondrian

I have a `Date` dimenstion with levels: `Year`, `Month`, `Day`. I am need to get average by month for range like this `[Date].[2011].[1].[10]:[Date].[2011].[10].[20]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something along these lines:

```
AVG(
  EXISTS(
    [Date].[Month].MEMBERS
    ,[Date].[2011].[1].[10]:[Date].[2011].[10].[20]
  )    
)
```

Or if you want the daily average:

```
AVG(
    [Date].[2011].[1].[10]:[Date].[2011].[10].[20]   
)
```

Or is you want the average by the count of number of days for the range you specified:

```
DIVIDE(
   SUM([Date].[2011].[1].[10]:[Date].[2011].[10].[20])
  ,EXISTS(
    [Date].[Month].MEMBERS
    ,[Date].[2011].[1].[10]:[Date].[2011].[10].[20]
   ).count
)
```

Comment: It wiil return me a wrong answear. I must use only a part of first and last monthes.